# Facebook like not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I used Facebook page like in my Android app. But it's only work my mobile because I am a administrator of this Facebook app. But when I use other account its not work. When I logout other account its popup login when click on like but after login other account Facebook like popup and then close without like. here is my code:

```
 void initFaceBook() {

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
    likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BOX_COUNT);
    likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
            "https://www.facebook.com/BangaliRannaRecipe",
            LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
}
```

My app gradel:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

I also make public my from App Review. [Here is the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bangaliapps.bangali_ranna) if you want to see this problem.

Comment: _what_ is the problem? Nobody here is going to install your app just to try and take a guess at what might be wrong with it. Voting to close for lack of context.

Comment: check your  facebook key for app(name) in live..if it live means green symbol showing

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable as public in facebook App Settings

- Go  facebook developer page.
- Select your app.
- Go to app review.
- Change into public  (Public means green symbol showing near app name)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by "**Submit Items for Approval**" that recently added by facebook. I provide my app apk and screen video then facebook approve me after 1.5 days. Now everything goes well.

[image]

Best of luck. :)